# Access two remote resources synchronously and output it in combined response - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express, meanjs

**In short.**

I need to access two or more remote resource feeds, combine it and show it as one result from my nodejs service.

---

**In detail**

I need to fetch the feeds from multiple providers *(which may vary in number according to what is stored in dashboard object)*

Concatenate them, do some other data manipulations and show the content as one array at the end.

```
var allFeeds = [];
dashboard.providers.forEach(function(provider) {
  if (provider.source === 'facebook') {
    ...
    fb.getFeeds(provider.data.id, function(feeds) {
      ...
      Array.prototype.push.apply(allFeeds, feeds);
    });
  } else if (provider.source === 'google') {
    ...
    google.getFeeds(provider.data.id, function(feeds) {
      ...
      Array.prototype.push.apply(allFeeds, feeds);
    });
  } else if (provider.source === 'twitter') {
    ...
    twitter.getFeeds(provider.data.id, function(feeds) {
      ...
      Array.prototype.push.apply(allFeeds, feeds);
    });
  }
});
...
// other data manipulations
...
res.json(allFeeds);
```

As nodejs is having asynchronous network calls how can I achieve this?

Comment: does your `getFeeds` callback return error also as first arguments of function ?

Comment: I wrote the `getFeeds` function. for the moment it's returning error in `feeds` as well.

Comment: Have a look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

```
var async = require('async');
var allFeeds = [];
var tasks = [];

dashboard.providers.forEach(function (provider) {
  if (provider.source === 'facebook') {
    ...
    tasks.push(function (done) {
      fb.getFeeds(provider.data.id, function (feeds) {
        ...
        Array.prototype.push.apply(allFeeds, feeds);
        done();
      });
    });
  } else if (provider.source === 'google') {
    ...
    tasks.push(function (done) {
      google.getFeeds(provider.data.id, function (feeds) {
        ...
        Array.prototype.push.apply(allFeeds, feeds);
        done();
      });
    });
  } else if (provider.source === 'twitter') {
    ...
    tasks.push(function (done) {
      twitter.getFeeds(provider.data.id, function (feeds) {
        ...
        Array.prototype.push.apply(allFeeds, feeds);
        done();
      });
    });
  }
});

async.parallel(tasks, function () {
  ...
  // other data manupulations
  ...
  res.json(allFeeds);
});
```

You can also check out this [post](http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/understand_node_without_losing_your_mind/) I wrote to structure your code to better manage async operations

Comment: Thank you :) I will check into async.js as well. This looks clean.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that with promises I will show you with [bluebird.js](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var fbFeedAsync = Promise.promisify(fb.getFeeds);
var googleFeedAsync = Promise.promisify(google.getFeeds);
var twitterFeedAsync = Promise.promisify(twitter.getFeeds); 

function getFeedFor(type, id) {
 if (type === 'twitter') {
  return twitterFeedAsync(id);
 } else if (type === 'google') {
  return googleFeedAsync(id);
 } else if (type === 'facebook') {
  return fbFeedAsync(id);
 }
}

var feedRequests = dashboard.providers.map(function(provider) { 
  return getFeedFor(provider.source, provider.data.id);
});

Promise.all(feedRequests).then(function(allFeeds) { // you can use Promise.settle (depending on your use case)
 console.log(allFeeds);
});
```

Comment: Thank you I'm checking into bluebird.js :)